# MediatR 12.2.0 behavior

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, mediatr

I am trying to implement simple logging behavior using MediatR, and I tried some registration in `Program.CS` but none of them didn't work.

```
using MediatR;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace CAS.TimeSheet.Application.Behaviors;

public class LoggingBehavior<TRequest, TResponse> : IPipelineBehavior<TRequest, TResponse>
    where TRequest : IRequest<TResponse>
{
    private readonly ILogger<LoggingBehavior<TRequest, TResponse>> _logger;

    public LoggingBehavior(ILogger<LoggingBehavior<TRequest, TResponse>> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task<TResponse> Handle(TRequest request, RequestHandlerDelegate<TResponse> next, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation($"Handling {typeof(TRequest).Name}");
        var response = await next();
        _logger.LogInformation($"Handled {typeof(TResponse).Name}");

        return response;
    }
}
```

and

```
builder.Services.AddMediatR(cfg =>
{
    cfg.RegisterServicesFromAssemblyContaining<HolidayService>();
    // cfg.AddBehavior(typeof(IPipelineBehavior<,>), typeof(LoggingBehavior<,>));
    // cfg.AddOpenBehavior(typeof(LoggingBehavior<,>));
});
// builder.Services.AddTransient(typeof(IPipelineBehavior<,>), typeof(LoggingBehavior<,>));
```

as you see I tried these registration:

1. `cfg.AddBehavior(typeof(IPipelineBehavior<,>), typeof(LoggingBehavior<,>));`
2. `cfg.AddOpenBehavior(typeof(LoggingBehavior<,>));`
3. `builder.Services.AddTransient(typeof(IPipelineBehavior<,>), typeof(LoggingBehavior<,>));`

Does someone know, what is the problem?

Comment: From my experience, `cfg.AddOpenBehavior(typeof(LoggingBehavior<,>));` should be the correct registration.

Comment: @jmoerdyk Thanks for your reply but unfortunately it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

In fact `cfg.AddOpenBehavior(typeof(LoggingBehavior<,>));` was working but I had forgotten something about the MediatR. I used post request and it worked.